# Find distance between multiple discrete sets of points QGIS3.8

Tags: qgis-3, point, line, distance

No similar question seems to relate to my issue but I desperately need help with calculating distances.
I have a CSV with the residential postcode of 200 000 patients. For each patient, I also have the postcode of their respective doctor. I need to find out how far, on average, patients are travelling to see their doctor.

So I've created centroids for all my postcodes thinking that a point layer would be easier to work with, but now I have no idea what to do. Old threads speak of plugins like Points2one that no longer exist (to my knowledge). 
I'm assuming I need to produce a line between all individual sets of points, then calculate the length of the lines and get the average.
Help!

Comment: Perhaps `Join by lines (hub lines)` tool will be useful. To prepare hub/spoke point layers, joining your csv to the centroids layer is not a problem for you?

Comment: Kazuhito that sounds promising- do you know any good tutorials for how to use that function?

Comment: Dee_ell_ess, I do not know any tutorial, but a [good example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307403/84455) posted by [MrXsquared](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/107424/mrxsquared) would be helpful.