# Lines Between Coordinate Points

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, coordinates, lines-to-points

Currently, I'm mapping data from the Hudson's Bay Company Archives in the nineteenth century, and I am tracing the routes travelled by fur traders. I have gone through the documents, recorded the start and end points of each trip, and the decimal coordinates of each. I created point data on Google Earth, exported the data as .kml files, and imported it all into QGIS. My current map looks like this:

[image: QGIS Screenshot of HBC Data]

I would like to have lines drawn between points on the map indicating the travels made by traders. Ideally, there would be a line for each voyage to a specific point, meaning heavily travelled routes are clearly visible to the observer.

Comment: using the processing toolbox (gear icon on your screenshot) look for "points to path" (under vector creation)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a great project! Here's two ideas for how to visualize the fur trapper's paths:

1. Straight lines. You can use the **Join by lines (hub lines)** in QGIS to connect origins/destinations. You'll need a "Hub" layer and a "Spoke" layer, with connecting points labeled by ID. If you know quantities (number of trips, volume of fur etc.) for each trip, you can input that as a field for each trip and use the value to control the thickness of the line. Look at the Center for Spatial Research's [Conflict Urbanism Colombia](https://juanfrans.com/2017/06/01/ConflictUrbanismColombia.html) project as an example.
2. Using a network. If you have a sense of what paths the trappers may have taken, especially if they overlap, you could create a third layer with a network of paths, then use **Shortest path (point to point)** to find paths along the network. Look at the [QGIS Network Analysis Tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html) for guidance. Each segment of the network could be given a different thickness based on the number of trips that pass through, to create a flow map. Look at the late 19th century [flow maps](https://datavizblog.com/2018/09/26/dataviz-as-maps-ministere-des-travaux-publics-album-de-statistique-graphique-de-1890-1891/) produced by the Ministry of Public Works in France.

Comment: This is great! I would definitely be using the Straight Lines for ease of interpretation. Is there a tutorial on how to use Join by Lines? I'm sure this is probably a really simple tool, but I'm really new to this program and have absolutely no experience. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Haven't seen a tutorial for this exact use case but have a look at this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307399/joining-many-points-with-lines. Good luck!